# oracle update first 4 characters with column value from another table

Tags: oracle

This is the query I am using to update a column with value from another table :

```
UPDATE SPICES A
  SET A.description = (SELECT CODE
                         FROM CHILLY B
                         WHERE SUBSTR(A.description,1,4) = TRIM(B.desc123))
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CHILLY B
                  WHERE SUBSTR(A.description,1,4) = TRIM(B.desc123));
```

But this is not what I want . The requirement is to update the first 4 characters of description with the new value (CODE) from table CHILLY.

Any suggestions? new to writing queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a concatenation operator for adding the rest of description

```
UPDATE SPICES A
SET A.description = (SELECT CODE
      FROM CHILLY B
      WHERE SUBSTR(A.description,1,4) = TRIM(B.desc123)) || SUSBSTR(A.description, 5, 255 )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM CHILLY B
               WHERE SUBSTR(A.description,1,4) = TRIM(B.desc123));
```